# Why doesn't the image update in my magnifier element?

Tags: javascript, angular

My component.ts is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { BusquedaService } from '../../services/busqueda.service';
import { UsuarioService } from '../../services/usuario.service';
// import { ZoomService } from '../../services/zoom.service';

// declare function magnify();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-adds-single-view',
  templateUrl: './adds-single-view.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class AddsSingleViewComponent implements OnInit {

  postId: string;
  category: any;
  postItem: any;
  articulo: any;
  imgID = 'myimage';

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              public busqueda: BusquedaService,
              public _usuario: UsuarioService) {

    this.postId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['postId'];
    this.category = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['cat'];

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.magnify();
    }, 2000);

    this.busqueda.busquedaEspecifica('ads-single-view', this.category, this.postId )
                 .subscribe((resp: any) => {
                    this.articulo = resp.articulos;
                    console.log(this.articulo);
                 });
  }

  changeFirstImage(data: any, data2: any) {
    const firstImgId = data;
    firstImgId.src = data2.src;
    this.imgID = data2.id;
    // const imgNewId = data.target.src;
    // let myImageSrc = document.getElementById('myimage');
  }

  magnify() {

    const zoom = 3;

    let img, glass, w, h, bw;
    img = document.getElementById(this.imgID);

    /*create magnifier glass:*/
    glass = document.createElement("DIV");
    glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");

    /*insert magnifier glass:*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);

    /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
    glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
    bw = 3;
    w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
    h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;

    /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
    glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);

    /*and also for touch screens:*/
    glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    function moveMagnifier(e) {
      var pos, x, y;
      /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
      e.preventDefault();
      /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
      pos = getCursorPos(e);
      x = pos.x;
      y = pos.y;
      /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
      if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
      if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
      if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
      if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
      /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
      glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
      glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
      /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
      glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
    }

    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0, y = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      y = e.pageY - a.top;
      /*consider any page scrolling:*/
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      y = y - window.pageYOffset;
      return {x : x, y : y};
    }
  }
}
```

the plugin works but I have the problem that when I change the image the zoom lens keeps showing the first image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhS4j.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9YLf.jpg)

probe executing the function that creates the magnifying glass inside the same function that changes the image but only duplicates the magnifying glass showing the first image and the current one:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo8ib.jpg)

Comment: Is the problem that `backgroundPosition` doesn't update as expected? Have you set a debug breakpoint on that line to see if the values are correct?